# How to convert Map to List in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to convert a `Map<String, Double>` to `List<Pair<String, Double>>` in Java 8?

I wrote this implementation, but it is not efficient

```
Map<String, Double> implicitDataSum = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
//....
List<Pair<String, Double>> mostRelevantTitles = new ArrayList<>();
implicitDataSum.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> -e.getValue()))
               .forEachOrdered(e -> mostRelevantTitles.add(new Pair<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue())));

return mostRelevantTitles;
```

I know that it should works using `.collect(Collectors.someMethod())`. But I don't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, you want to collect `Pair` elements into a `List`. That means that you need to map your `Stream<Map.Entry<String, Double>>` into a `Stream<Pair<String, Double>>`.

This is done with the [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) operation:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

In this case, the function will be a function converting a `Map.Entry<String, Double>` into a `Pair<String, Double>`.

Finally, you want to collect that into a `List`, so we can use the built-in [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) collector.

```
List<Pair<String, Double>> mostRelevantTitles = 
    implicitDataSum.entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> -e.getValue()))
                   .map(e -> new Pair<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that you could replace the comparator `Comparator.comparing(e -> -e.getValue())` by `Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())`.

Comment: Note that `-e.getValue()` does not reorder NaNs. Forward order assumes having `Double.NaN` values at the end of the list. Using unary minus you will revert everything *except* NaNs: they still will be at the end of the list.

Comment: Yeah, `Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())` or `Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())`. If comparing the negative values is intended [Tagir explained the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107550/how-to-convert-map-to-list-in-java-8#comment57966768_35107595), then `Comparator.comparingDouble` should be preferred to avoid reboxing of the values.

Answer (score 9):

Note that if you want *efficient* implementation, you should consider this:

```
List<Pair<String, Double>> mostRelevantTitles = 
    implicitDataSum.entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .map(e -> new Pair<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
mostRelevantTitles.sort(Comparators.comparing(Pair::getSecond, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

I assume that your `Pair` class have `getSecond` getter.

Using the `sorted()` stream pipeline step you create intermediate buffer, store everything to that buffer, convert it into array, sort that array, then store the result into the `ArrayList`. My approach, though less functional, stores data directly into the target `ArrayList`, then sorts it in-place without any additional copying. So my solution would take less time and intermediate memory.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public List<TeamResult> process(final Map<String, Team> aggregatedMap) {
   return aggregatedMap.entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .map(e -> new TeamResult(e.getKey(),e.getValue()))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the Map based on values in reverse order and collect the keys in list and also limit only first 2 results in the list

```
    List<String> list = map.keySet().stream()
                .sorted((k1, k2)->map.get(k2)- map.get(k1))
                .limit(2)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
```